# Will leaves decay from trees we "make"?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Will the leaves of the trees I plant artificially (i.e the leaves surrounding a wood block that is placed by me) decay away?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Edit:** As of Minecraft Beta 1.8, blocks placed manually by the player don't decay, even if they aren't within 4 blocks of a Wood block.

---

<s>Leaves that you place are the exact same as leaves that grow naturally on trees – there is no distinction (in the code) between them. The leaves that you place (and leaves on natural trees) will not decay as long as they are within 4 blocks of a log block.</s>

Comment: @fireDude The planned update is to make leaves never decay if they're placed, no matter if there's a log or not.